# How to make an extra JMenuBar and JLabel to a game made by a gameengine?

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I have a game made with my game engine Java class.
The game engine uses paintComponent to draw the elements.
Here is a snippet from the game:
[gamepic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QhZa.png)

I want to add this game an extra JLabel and JMenu to the top or the button of the game.

Here is my code:

```
public class LabyrinthGUI {

    private JFrame frame;
    private GameEngine gameArea;
    private String PlayerName;

    public LabyrinthGUI(String PlayerName) {
        frame = new JFrame("GAME");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

         //making new manu bar
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu sg = new JMenu("Settings");
        JMenuItem ng = new JMenuItem("New game");
        

        mb.add(ng);
        mb.add(sg);

        frame.getContentPane().add(mb);
        gameArea = new GameEngine(PlayerName);//This is a game engine 

      
        JLabel l1 = new JLabel("First Label.");  
        l1.setBounds(50,50, 100,30);  
         frame.add(l1);
            

        frame.getContentPane().add(gameArea);

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);


    }
```

The problem with my code is it does not seem to add the JLabel and JMenuBar to the game.

Comment: Huh? You add 2 components JMenuBar & JLabel to JFrame (not to the gameArea) and they have nothing to do with the paintComponent, heven't they?

Answer (score 1):

To add a `JMenuBar` to your `JFrame` you have to use the [`setJMenuBar()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setJMenuBar(javax.swing.JMenuBar)) method:

> `public void setJMenuBar(JMenuBar menubar)`
>
> Sets the menubar for this frame.
>
> Parameters:
>
> - `menubar` - the menubar being placed in the frame
>
> See Also:
>
> `getJMenuBar()`

So you use it like:

```
frame.setJMenuBar(mb);
```

For the label and the game engine being added to the content pane: A `JFrame` uses the [`BorderLayout` layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) as default for placing the components on the pane. See the documentation of [`JFrame`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html):

> The default content pane will have a `BorderLayout` manager set on it.

Because you haven't specify the locations where exactly you want to place the components with the `BorderLayout` layout manager, the component will be placed in the [`CENTER`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html#CENTER). However there can only be one component at a slot defined by the `BorderLayout` layout manager. The latest added component will override previous placed components (in the same slot), so your added `JLabel` will be overridden by the later added game engine. Depending on how/where you want to place the `JLabel` and your game engine, you have to use a different layout manager or specify where you want to place the components with the `BorderLayout` layout manager.

Answer (score 0):

The way to add a JMenuBar to a JFrame is not:

```
frame.getContentPane().add(mb);
```

but:

```
this.frame.setJMenuBar(mb);
```

Take a look at [Creating Menus](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#create) section in the Java Tutorial.